# Google Chome extension, too add JavaScript to pages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'll try to be as descriptive as possible.

Here an extension for Google Chrome, [Stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha?hl=en). This allows to apply some CSS code on a page, this allowing you to stylize this page like you want. With this tool I'm able to edit the styles of the web pages I use in order to hide Ads or other page elements I do not like when access it. The problem is that this too allows only to edit CSS code, but what i need for now, is a similar too that will allow to do the same, but with JavaScript coding. So whenever I would access this web page, that script will apply automatically.

Does anyone know such Google Chrome extension that would allow this?

Thank You,
George

Comment: This might be a better question to ask on [superuser](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon)